# In Bootcamp, I can't get past the "Create Partition for Windows" stage

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I've been trying to install a copy of Windows 7 on my MacBook Air, but I have not been able to get past the "Crate a Partition for Windows" stage. I tried clicking on the "Install" button, but nothing happened. I wonder what is going on. Just for your info, if it matters, I have a 2011 MBA (1.7 GHz Intel Core i5, 128 GB SSD, 4 GB ram, and I have OSX 10.8.4 installed). Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I remember having this problem with my 2009 MacBook Air. I never did manage to actually fix it, but I ended up **making the partition using Disk Utility**. This seemed to work fine.

Comment: After you made a partition, how did you install Windows? My impression (which may well be wrong) is that I somehow have to create the windows partition via Bootcamp.

Comment: @Alex Boot Camp is just a wizard to make it *easier* to install Windows and is not required. I used Boot Camp Assistant to create a USB installer, then partitioned using Disk Utility. Booting with ⌥ let me select the USB drive, and in the Windows install process I chose the partition that I made, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. In my case, I was using FileVault and the initial encryption phase hadn’t completed yet.

Once FileVault was done (encrypted the drive) I was able to successfully create the partition.